# jQueryUI - Autocomplete not displaying drop-down with json

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to make an autocomplete with a .jsp file but the drop-down doesn't show up.

```
var cod = document.getElementById('item').value;

$('input#item').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "autocomplete.jsp?cod="+cod,
          dataType: "json",
          minLength: 2,
          data: {
            maxRows: 12
          },
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              response(data);
          }
        });
      }
});
```

I looked at 'Networks' on Chrome and it calls the url with the parameter and returns OK but the drop-down doesn't show up. PS.: that alert dialog from 'alert(data)' is also not showing up.

Comment: its means there is some problem in the call which you are making..try putting error: block and see if you are getting any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working too hard--doing some things you don't need to.  And some of the parameters intended for the autocomplete function are being passed to the ajax function instead--minLength, for instance.  Let's restructure that call like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('input#item').autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.jsp?maxRows=12',
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.value + ' ' + ui.item.label);
        },
    });
});
```

In your jsp, instead of "cod" you will receive a parameter named "term."  This is the automatic behavior of the autocomplete widget.

Your jsp will need to return a JSON array. Each element of this array is also an array with two members, a "value" and a "label."

Comment: still not working... I put a error: alert('error') and it shows up every time I type something on the input field. My input field html: <div class="ui-widget"> <input id="item"> </div>

Comment: Your code worked. I took a look on my code and there were some syntax mistakes. Thanks.